# How to integrate ZXing api with front camera in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I just wanted to integrate ZXing API in my android app, but cant find the proper documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Follow these steps:

1) Download the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout

2) Import the source code as a new project into Eclipse and make the root of the project be the folder /android (found in the source code).

3) Make sure to also copy everything under /core/src to this project, as the source code imported on step 2 requires it.

4) Make sure to set your compiler to Java 1.6 on Eclipse (right click on your project, properties, Java Compiler) otherwise you will get some errors regarding the @Override annotation.

5) Edit the class com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface as follows:

```
  while (index < numCameras) {
       Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
       Camera.getCameraInfo(index, cameraInfo);


       if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
           break;
       }
       /*//Original code (gets the back camera. This is NOT what you want!)
       if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
    break;
  }*/
  index++;
}
```

5) Make this project as a library, as easily described here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

6) Reference this project into your real project (right click on your real project, properties, Java Build Path, Projects, Add).

7) You're done! =)

Hope it helps.

Comment: nice description Tiago :)

Comment: Hai Tiago, I implemented the front camera as you insisted. But it doesn't scan and getting the result. A simple camera view is showing. If i show the Barcode in front of it. nothing happens. No stack trace. What might be the problem? Would you please help me

Comment: The problem is likely the front camera you are using does not have autofocus, which makes it really difficult to read barcodes. Front cameras usually have their focus locked (to make them cheaper) which makes them not good for close objects. I have also had problems with front cameras to read barcodes because of the lack of autofocus. Sometimes it would take more than 1 minute until I could manage to make it recognise the barcode. Other times, I could not make the camera read the barcode at all. The problem is not in the software but in the camera itself.

Comment: Can you go into detail on this a bit more? Download. Now I see 4 different projects. Core/src has 1 file in it. More worrying GingerbreadOpenCameraInterface  does not exist at all according to a search of the whole archive. Maybe they changed too much. In that case the version you used would be helpful. Even better would just be your example posted somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) as well as the [ZXing source code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing) now supports front facing camera.

Comment: I search for it in preferences but cannot find the settings. How do you do that ?

Comment: @Natim I remember it being handled automatically. The back facing camera is used by default, but if there is no such camera the front facing camera is used instead.

Comment: My back camera is broken, I wish I could try with the front one.

Comment: Its not in settings. I don't think you are correct. Also I need to be able to launch it directly.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

As the ZXing's FAQ has been updated since I posted this answer, the content below is no longer accurate:

<strike>Have you read ZXing's [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)?</strike>

> **Can this be used on Android devices with only a front-facing camera, like the Nexus 7 tablet?** Not at this time. The application requires
> a camera. In Android, only rear cameras are considered 'real' cameras,
> and so devices with only a front camera are incompatible. Further, API
> support for front cameras appeared in a later Android release than is
> currently required by the app. Front-facing cameras tend to have a
> less sensitive CCD and lack auto-focus, making them difficult to scan
> with anyway.
>
> However, [Barcode Scanner+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.srowen.bs.android) does support devices with only a front
> camera.

Besides, although I think this is not totally impossible if you can connect the front camera. Therefore, I think you should take a look at the Camera Section of Android Documentation: [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html)

Comment: (This is no longer true and the FAQ item has been removed.)

Comment: @SeanOwen Thanks, i've stroke out my answer