# ZXing android use front camera

Tags: android, zxing

I'm trying to build a QR Code reader following this tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

I managed to get everything working, except that I need the camera to be the front camera of my device instead of the rear camera. I can't find any place in the tutorial that allows me to change this. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642112/how-to-integrate-zxing-api-with-front-camera-in-android) answer, but I still could not get it to work.

Mainly, my issue is with importing the library. I get the following error.

```
operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
```

When I set my compiler settings to 1.7, I get this

```
Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead
```

I'm not exactly very proficient with Android and I apologize if it might not be a good question.

So, any way for me to use ZXing with the front camera in my app? Any links?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The source code uses Java 7. Android does not require Java <= 6. You can see that the build provided in the project happily feeds Java 7 bytecode to dex and produces a working app. I am not sure what tool you are using that suggests otherwise. Maybe it is old.

You should not need to copy and compile the project's code though. Why is that necessary? use the `core.jar` file.

You don't need any of this to use the front camera. Just invoke by Intent (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent) and set extra `SCAN_CAMERA_ID` to the ID of the camera you want -- usually 1 for the front one.

Example:

```
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_CAMERA_ID", 1);
```

Comment: I tried to use the front camera by stting the `SCAN_CAMERA_ID` extra to 1, but the barcode scanner app always starts using the back camera. Is there any limitation to specific devices which can use the front camera?

Comment: perfect, just what I needed!

Comment: Note, They did not write ZXing to be used like a normal library. You will need to use the integration library, which more or less launches the application or if not installed, the app store. See their androidtest as an example.. though not complete compatible with this answer. You will end up with something like 

       Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                intent.putExtra("SCAN_CAMERA_ID", 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Answer (score 3):

If you use [IntentIntegrator](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent#intentintegrator), you can use `setCameraId()` to specify the front camera:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
integrator.setCameraId(1);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Comment: Additionally, you need to check if the device has more than one camera, then pass in one of ```android.hardware.camera2``` constants: ```CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_BACK, CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_FRONT``` or ```CameraMetadata.LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL```

Answer (score 2):

After quite a few search i found how to use the front camera. There is this piece of code in **com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.CameraConfigurationManager.java**

```
public void openDriver(SurfaceHolder holder) throws IOException {
Camera theCamera = camera;
if (theCamera == null) {
  theCamera = Camera.open();
  if (theCamera == null) {
    throw new IOException();
  }
  camera = theCamera;
}
theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
```

jus change the **Camera.open()** to **Camera.open(1)** 
worked fine for me